# How to calculate divergence of vector field on a rotated grid in Metpy?

Tags: metpy

I need to calculate the divergence of u(M,N) and v(M,N) from a limit-area-model with a rotated grid. Here u and v are the x- and y-component of the wind. The latitude and longitude of the grid are given in 2D arrays: lats(M,N) lons(M,N).

Should I rotate (u, v) to the zonal (East-West) and meridional (North-South) components before using the following metpy function?

metpy.calc.divergence(u, v, *, dx=None, dy=None, x_dim=- 1, y_dim=- 2)

I calculate dx and dy with the following function:

dx, dy = metpy.calc.lat_lon_grid_deltas(lons, lats)

Is it correct for a rotated grid?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using those `dx` and `dy` values calculated from longitude and latitude, that presumes that the wind components are in that same frame of reference.

There's also an [open issue](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/893) on MetPy to make all of the derivatives of vector quantities (i.e. wind velocity) operate with better accuracy in projected coordinates, accounting for the effects of map projections.

Comment: Thank you very much, Doppler. Now I need to deal with the projected coordinate issue.